# How to prevent NetworkImage from crushing debugger?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-image

I am trying to run a debugger in my flutter app. Whenever the app tries to load NetworkImage with invalid URL debugger crashes. It makes debugging very complicated because I need to comment out all images in the app to prevent this from happening while debugging app.
I can't find any possible way to resolve this issue except to try editing source code of the NetworkImage which doesn't seem right. Here is the last line executed before debugger crashes. Any idea how to resolve this issue is highly appreciated!
[image]